# Acer Aspire 5742 webcam zoomed in on websites, works fine with normal applications

Tags: webcam

When I use my webcam on websites Eg: www.tinychat.com it's really zoomed in, although when i use it on applications such as Cheese, Kamoso, or Skype, it's absolutely fine. I've tried reinstalling cheese, reinstalling ubuntu all together, no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, it's only since 12.04 that this has happened,

My system is an Acer Aspire 5742 and it's the built in webcam.

Answer (score 0):

Tinychat.com uses Flash to work with your camera

Check your camera with the this [site](http://www.testmycam.com/), for example.

If the image problem is the same, then this is a Flash related issue.